# Django showing msgid instead of msgstring

Tags: python, django, gettext

I have correctly set `LOCALE_PATHS` in my settings.

`LANGUAGE_CODE` is set to `it`.

As a test, the only language I translated the app into is `it`.

In one of my views I have `{% trans "MY_MESSAGE_ID" %}` and in `django.po` I have

```
msgid "MY_MESSAGE_ID"
msgstr "It is working"
```

---

If a visitor with `it` language opens the app, he sees `"It is working"`

If a visitor with `en` language opens the app, he sees `"MY_MESSAGE_ID"`

Django should **never** display `msgid` to the end-user. Django should serve the first available translation as a fallback, **especially** if I defined it in `LANGUAGE_CODE`. Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

---

The solution to this problem, I read, is to use `"It is working"` as a message id. I believe this solution is unacceptable for these reasons:

- Making a `en` translation would be useless, since the message ids are
  already the translation itself.
- Some message ids would be extremely long.
- "Message id" refers to something which **must** be language-agnostic.
- If I wanted to change the default language, I'd have to re-write the entire application text content.

Comment: Have you compiled the default .po into an English translation with the correct path?

Comment: No. The en translation is not available, on purpose. I wanted to see how Django behaves when the translation in the user language is not available. It should ALWAYS serve a translation and never, EVER, the messages ids.

Comment: The only translation I have compiled is "it". I could also compile "en". What then if a German user opens the website? According to the current behavior, it will display the messages ids instead of falling back to a default language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fall back to multiple languages in Django at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577722/how-to-fall-back-to-multiple-languages-in-django-at-runtime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django, like many others uses the `gettext` internally; likewise the `.mo`, `.po` formats belong and are produced by their utilities. You are not using the full power of `gettext` if you do not use the full message as the `msgid`.

See for example the documentation for glibc:

> ## SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> #include <libintl.h>
>
> char * gettext (const char * msgid);
> char * dgettext (const char * domainname, const char * msgid);
> char * dcgettext (const char * domainname, const char * msgid,
>                   int category);
> ```
>
> ### DESCRIPTION
>
> The gettext, dgettext and dcgettext functions attempt to translate a text string into the user's native language, by looking up
>   the translation in a message catalog.
>
> The  msgid  argument  identifies the message to be translated. **By convention, it is the English version of the message, with
>   non-ASCII characters replaced by ASCII approximations.** This choice allows the translators to work with message catalogs, called PO files, that contain both the English and the translated versions of each message,  and  can
>   be installed using the msgfmt utility.

In addition, with GNU gettext comes the utility `msgen`, that

> Creates  an English translation catalog.  The input file is the last created English PO file, or a PO Template file (generally created by xgettext).  Untranslated entries are assigned a translation that is identical to the msgid.

Furthermore, the `gettext` utilities can find fuzzy matches for new messages, which will speed up translation effort, and also notice when a translation is out of date and mark it for retranslation. This is impossible if you use nonsensical message IDs in your templates.